# c# casting string to class object

Tags: c#, sql

i want to cast a string from database to a class object without having to go over each possible outcome.

so not

```
if(type.StartsWith("ContactPersonType")){//} else if(type.StartsWith("ContactPersonTitle")){//}
```

this is what i have so far

```
        private static T Create<T>(IDataRecord record)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var returnVal = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        properties.ToList().ForEach(item =>
        {
            string type = item.GetMethod.ReturnParameter.ParameterType.Name;
            if (type.StartsWith("ContactPerson"))
            {
                Type t = Type.GetType(item.GetMethod.ReturnParameter.ParameterType.ToString());
                item.SetValue(returnVal, Convert.ChangeType(record[item.Name].ToString(), t));
            }
            else if (!type.StartsWith("ObservableCollection"))
            {
                item.SetValue(returnVal, Convert.ChangeType(record[item.Name].ToString(), item.PropertyType));
            }

        });
        return (T)returnVal;
    }

public class ContactPersonType
{
    private int _id;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private String _name;
    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous collection when you want a certain action to apply to different input values.

```
foreach(var option in new[] {"ContactPerson", "ContactPersonTitle" }){
   if (type.StartsWith(option))
   {
        Type t = Type.GetType(item.GetMethod.ReturnParameter.ParameterType.ToString());
        item.SetValue(returnVal, Convert.ChangeType(record[item.Name].ToString(), t));
   }
}
```

Comment: invalidCasteException

Comment: item.SetValue(returnVal, Convert.ChangeType(record[item.Name].ToString(), t));

Comment: Invalid conversion from System.String to ProjectFestival.model.ContactPersonType.

Comment: Sounds like an `enum`? Use `Enum.TryParse()` on the string first to get the correct enum type.